# Google Plus Signin Android Invalid Service

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to sign in using google plus on my app, I have generated the certificate fingerprint and all, yet when I go to get a token using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` I always get this error.

Error Log:

```
09-04 14:04:39.904  13462-13474/? E/GLSUser: Empty consent data

09-04 14:04:39.904  13462-13474/? I/GLSUser: GLS error: InvalidService
```

This is the code I am using to try to get the token

```
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:oauth2:%s", CLIENT_ID,     Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " " + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, plusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to specify the server api key in the google api console under the section **key for android apps with certificates**

```
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:%s:client_id:%s:oauth2:%s", API_KEY, CLIENT_ID, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " " + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scope string (oauth2) doesn't look correct, it should be:

```
"oauth2:server:client_id:<server client-id>:api_scope:<scope1> <scope2>";
```

Where `<scope1>` is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

And `<scope2>` and so on are the additional scopes you are authorizing.

Comment: Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN is the scope for    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login defined in the com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes class

Comment: Yes, you should be using the scopes constants, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hey @class, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown.  Any idea why? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: @toobsco42 remove the userinfo.profile scope and you should be golden.